# Strange black bars with sun beams node?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, effects

So, when compositing using the sun beams node (and using an *Add* mix node), the sun beams node itself works, but I get some strange black bars:

[image: Black bars]

How can I fix this?
I've tried on multiple computers.

[image]

Comment: Could you show your node setup, give some reference about where the bars are and more info in general about your scene? Are you able to tell the passage to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Carlo As far as I'm aware the node setup doesn't matter (as long as it actually does have a sun beams node), as I've had this issue many times before. My scene simply comprises of a solidified plane with an emission shader and a small landscape down below.

EDIT: Could this be because I used an Add node to add the sun beams effect (instead of a multiply/screen/whatever)?

Comment: Could you upload to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ the simplest scene showing the problem? I was not able to reproduce it on my own with your instruction.

Comment: @Carlo that's odd... with pleasure.

Comment: @Carlo Well, the problem is avoiding me now. I'll get back if/when it comes back.

Comment: @Carlo source added to OP. I recreated it, just hit render and you should see a black bar down the left.

Comment: I see...it looks like a failure in rendering pixel color for rays that are perpendicullary pointing from the source to the camera, I can't tell why it's happening, but seems that slightly moving the light source (e.g. x factor = 0.801 intead of 0.800) would help you avoid that issue.

Comment: @Carlo I realised that this would solve my problem, but sometimes it's annoying because my source is already in the best spot :c

Ed: Oh, wait, you're talking extremely minute values. :P I'll try and then get back.